# Executing r code through PHP and returning result

Tags: php, r, exec

I want to execute code through a button on my webpage via PHPs `exec()` function. I have never done anything with PHP so please be gentle with me :D

My problem is:

How can I input commands into the opened program and get back the result ?

in my PHP file I open R with

```
exec("R");
```

But how do I know, weather R has been started or not? 
And how can I inject something like

```
2+2
```

and receive the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that executable offers to hand over the actual code you can do so, otherwise you have to setup a separate process and use sockets to communicate with that. But a general note: it is extremely questionable if you _really_ want to do that. This opens _huge_ security issues for your system...

Comment: The security aspect is not that much of a problem since it is for a project for my university and is not intended to go live. But I understand what you mean and why it is that much of a problem.

Comment: Intersting. My experience is that _especially_ in university environments people tend to "use networks in a very creative approach", to put it that way.  Which is both understandable and actually good, once you think about it. So don't let yourself be fooled into a false sense of security, your code will be miss used faster that you can look ;-)

Comment: @arkascha I guess you are right :D I don't know how else to approach my problem :D I want the website im working on to enable the input of r-code (for analysis purposes only ;) ) and I want to process this code on my server and post back the result. I thought php was a good way to start R and inject the code and post back the result from my serverside  :/

Comment: As said: this probably is possible. I only _added_ that warning to my initial comment on how you might approach what you try to do.

Comment: For the security implications you _may_ want to look at using virutalization, especially docker containers, which would reliably separate that unknown code from your host system.